# Children probability problem

Tags: probability

Here is the problem:

Suppose the probability of a child being born boy is $\frac12$. If a couple has 2 kids, then what is the chance that:

1. the first is a boy and the second is a girl
2. they have a boy and a girl no matter the order
3. they have 2 boys or 2 girls

Here is what my intuition and very little understanding of probabilities say.

1. All the possible outcomes are $\{bb, gg, bg, gb\}$ and since we want the probability of $bg$, that must be $\frac14$.
2. Since order doesn't matter the sample space is $\{bb, gg, bg(gb)\}$. So the answer here would be $\frac13$.
3. Here I don't quite know what to think of the "or". What I assume is that it means either one is the same. So it would be $\Omega=\{bb(gg), bg, gb\}$ and since it doesn't say that order is irrelevant I would go with $\frac13$.

Now I also have the answers to the questions $\frac14,\frac12 \text{and} \frac12$ respectively, but not the methodology. Considering that there had been some mistakes in previous exercises, I want to know if I am wrong or the teacher is?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. As you can see I made some changes in your question to make it more readable. As a newcommer I would like to suggest you read the about page... http://math.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample space is always $\{bb,gg,bg,gb\}$, also for question 2) and 3). Therefor the answer for 2) is $\frac12$. You shouldn't consider $(bg)$ and $(gb)$ to be the same event. I think this will help you with 3) as well...

(The "*or*" in your question usually indicates that you have to add probabilities. An "*and*" usually indicates you have to multiply.)

Comment: So you are saying that no matter what the problem tells me i will always account for both (bg) and (gb) in the possible outcomes? If so how does the "order doesn't matter" in the second question affect the answer?

Comment: @Dim.Tsach.  That is correct. And saying "the order doesn't" matter is just to emphasize the fact that *the order doesn't matter*. If you leave it out some people might mistake question 2) for question 1).

Comment: So for 3) the answer is 1/4 for bb and 1/4 for gg. But i don't understand if i have to add those possibilities to get the correct answer or if it's just 1/4.

Comment: As I said, the *or* indicates you must add...

Comment: @dim And you are correct about the odds of $bb$ and $gg$